# MySQL Get Highest Score with Fastest Time

Tags: mysql, datetime

**Quiz result statistics:**

```
UserId StartDate            EndDate              UserScore
1      2015-03-04 14:01:26  2015-03-04 14:02:14  200
2      2015-03-04 14:01:26  2015-03-04 14:02:14  180
3      2015-03-04 13:42:23  2015-03-04 13:43:19  200
4      2015-03-04 13:07:52  2015-03-04 13:08:57  160
```

Data type for StartDate/EndDate is `datetime`. Units to get time should be in `seconds`

How can I fetch Highest user score with fastest time (minimum time taken) to complete quiz ?

Comment: What data type is `StartDate`/`EndDate`?  Timestamps or strings (VARCHAR, CHAR...)?

Comment: We also have to worry about the case where two users have the same quiz time but different UserScore values.

Comment: start and end date are `datetime`

Comment: What units do you want for the minimum time?  Seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: Unit should be seconds. But first user will be ordered by  highest score and in case if two users have same score they will then be ordered based on minimum time taken to complete the quiz

Comment: How you define the rank ? lets say one user got 200 in 40 mins and another user got 190 in 30 mins, what is the logic to decide the rank here ?

Comment: I asked that question in a comment to my answer below.  He wants to rank first by score, and then rank by fastest time in the event of a tied score.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, user with the highest score will be awarded.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy checkout answer from Tim, this will do what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

We need to handle the case where there may be more than one record which has the fastest time (a tie).  In this case, we can `ORDER` the results descending by `UserScore` (i.e. scores get worst going down the result set), but keep only the top record:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, StartDate, EndDate)
AS fastest_time
FROM score_table
ORDER BY UserScore DESC, fastest_time ASC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Yes, we need top 3 scorers for the quiz result where they will be fetched on the basis of highest score and minimum time taken to finish that quiz.

Comment: OK...but which metric gets first priority?  Consider two students: Student A takes 5 minutes with a score of 90.  Student B is the next fastest taking 7 minutes but with a score of 100.  Who ranks higher?

Comment: `Score` would be the first priority but if there are two users with same scores then the minimum time taken metric would also come into picture.

Comment: Executing the above query outputs `fastest_time = -79443`

Comment: Have a look at my query.  First I `ORDER BY` on the `UserScore` and then I `ORDER BY` the minimum time, in case of two or three students having the same score.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, StartDate, EndDate))
AS fastest_time, UserScore, UserId
FROM score_table
ORDER BY UserScore DESC, fastest_time ASC LIMIT 3` gives me incorrect results

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Single record with lowest user score which is the first record in table

Comment: Please play around with the above query.  I can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: The query seems okay, but why it fetches only one and the first record ? On executing it says `This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available`

Comment: I know what I did wrong!  I used an aggregator function `MIN` in the query.  This is why you are getting only one record!  I will fix now...please stand by.